# libnss-ldapd and Onelogin vLDAP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ldap, pam

I'm trying to get Onelogin's new vLDAP service working with libnss-ldapd on an Ubuntu server (14.04).

It looks like [vLDAP](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/206444116-Using-the-OneLogin-Virtual-LDAP-Service) uses authenticated bind per user. I've tried lots of different configurations but it seems that overall libnss-ldapd wants to bind to the directory (either anonymously or with a single bind user), then search for a given user.

Does anyone know if this sort of configuration is supported with libnss-ldapd?

Ultimately I'm trying to achieve chrooted SSH login with authentication via Onelogin.